# Arduino Communication with Xbee

Tags: programming

I'm trying to establish a wireless connection between two Arduino's(M0) using xbee s2c, one Arduino as the sender and other as the receiver. But I am not able to receive the message what the Arduino is sending.

The two radio modules are configured as:

**Sender**

```
pan id- 1234
CE- enable
DH- 13A200
DL- 40F8D876
AP- Transparent mode
```

**Receiver**

```
pan id- 1234
CE- Disable
JV- Enable
DH- 13A200
DL- 40F8D874
AP- Transparent mode
```

**SENDER CODE**

```
void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  SerialUSB.print(int(Serial1.write("1"))); 
  delay(1000);
}
```

**RECEIVER CODE**

```
void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()){
  SerialUSB.print(int(Serial1.read())); 
  delay(1000);
}}
```